# Do I need cookies to get this to work?

Tags: javascript, css, cookies

I want to use something like this code for changing background-color and text-color of my webpage. 
It is useful for changing your header bg-color, color, and your menu drop down background-color and color. but NOT the color of the menu, or the top bar of the menu. Just affects the boxes that drop down, so neat code.

But if I want to "remember" the choice for my entire webpage, like have a user have the option to change color cheme, not changing stylesheets however, as I have stylesheets for different widths and heigths etc.

Do I have to use cookies, to do what I want here?

Purple COLOR Js

```
function greenColor(){     document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundColor = "purple";
            document.getElementById("copyW").style.backgroundColor = "purple";
            document.getElementById("text").style.backgroundColor = "white";

                            var parentElement =     document.getElementById("text");
            var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("p");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

            lis[i].setAttribute("style","color: black");

            }

        var parentElement = document.getElementById("cssmenu");
            var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("ul");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

            lis[i].setAttribute("style","background-color: purple");

            }

                            var parentElement =
document.getElementById("webpage");
            var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

            lis[i].setAttribute("style","color: black");

    }
    }
```

RED COLOR Js

```
    function redColor(){
            document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundColor = "red";
            document.getElementById("copyW").style.backgroundColor = "red";
            document.getElementById("text").style.backgroundColor = "white";

                            var parentElement =     document.getElementById("text");
            var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("p");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

            lis[i].setAttribute("style","color: black");

            }

            var parentElement = document.getElementById("cssmenu");
            var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("ul");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

            lis[i].setAttribute("style","background-color: red");

            }


                        var parentElement = document.getElementById("webpage");
            var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

            lis[i].setAttribute("style","color: black");

            }
            }
```

High contrast Js

```
function contrastColor(){
            document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundColor = "black";
            document.getElementById("copyW").style.backgroundColor = "grey";
            document.getElementById("text").style.backgroundColor = "black";
                var parentElement = document.getElementById("text");
            var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("p");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

            lis[i].setAttribute("style","color: white");

            }



            var parentElement = document.getElementById("cssmenu");
            var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("ul");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

            lis[i].setAttribute("style","background-color: black");

            }
                var parentElement = document.getElementById("webpage");
            var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

            lis[i].setAttribute("style","color: white");

            }

            }
            function normalColor(){
            document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundColor = "green";
            document.getElementById("copyW").style.backgroundColor = "green";
            document.getElementById("text").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                var parentElement = document.getElementById("text");
            var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("p");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

            lis[i].setAttribute("style","color: black");

             }



            var parentElement = document.getElementById("cssmenu");
            var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("ul");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

            lis[i].setAttribute("style","background-color: green");

            }
                var parentElement = document.getElementById("webpage");
            var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

            lis[i].setAttribute("style","color: black");

            }

            }
```

Then this is the Css

```
#buttons{
z-index:1;      
display:inline;
border: none;
height:1em;
top:7.5em;
position:absolute;
right:0em;
}
#normal {
background:#008000;
background-size:cover;
cursor:pointer;
}
#purple{
    background:purple;
    background-size:cover;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
#red {
    background:#FF0000;
    background-size:cover;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
#contrast{
    background:black;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:cover;
    }
```

My html is simply a header, and a footer that changes color of the background, and then a High contrast version also, wich changes text color also, therefore I set "fallbacks", or chose to change it to black text color in javascript naturally.

Is it then, possible to change for my entire webpage, and then if I have to use cookies to do this, How do I set up the cookiething to have a choice of saving the color-sheme, or not, when the user chooses the color?

In advance thank you for any help:)
And is it possible to change style of css3-animations, in javascript, like i am doing with background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use local storage to store the user's selected color. As an example, here is [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmefL6a7/)

**jQuery**

```
// add a handeler to a color picker element
$('#myColor').change(function() {

    // get the color from the changed picker
    var colorCode = $(this).val();

    // set the color to our header
    $("#myHeader").css("background-color", colorCode );

    // save the color to the browser's `localstorage`
    localStorage.setItem("colorCode", colorCode) ;
});


// when page loads, check if user has a colorcode stored in local storage
if (localStorage.getItem("colorCode") !== null) {

    // if so, set the color to our header and the picker
    var colorCode = localStorage.getItem("colorCode");
    $('#myColor').val( colorCode );
    $("#myHeader").css("background-color", colorCode );
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myHeader"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Pick a color: <input type="color" id="myColor" value="#cccccc" />
```

**CSS**

```
#myHeader{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#cccccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use cookies. I would recommend using `localStorage` instead if you don't need the server to get involved with the user's color setting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with cookies.  But this might be something better for `localStorage`.  A couple benefits to localStorage are:

1. localStorage has no expiration as opposed to cookies
2. localStorage has a 5mb storage capacity.  This is significantly larger than cookies ~4kb
3. localStorage is served up on the client side which removes extra http requests.

Comment: that is useful, thanks :)

acreating my webpage, I have startet to think about that I have a lot of html pages. I was referred to php, and now use ajax to change the content of my "text-div", or main content in my page.. 
This let me have "only" 9 html pages, all of wich are in my "mainmenu", and each a separate html-page.. Php someone told me, is good to get it all into less pages, but how exactly would I go about and achieve this?

Comment: I am thinking about, if I add a menu-item, I would have to change this in every html page.. Is the main-menu a good thing, to also load in with ajax? Or does this leave my page voulnerable if ajax was to fail or sometthing like that? :)

Answer (score 0):

localstorage seemed to be the way to go, thanks. 
When constructing the webpage thou, I have tried to make it mobile friendly..
My first thought was to have hidden(display:none), links, at the bottom of the page, since I have a hover menu in my webpage version.
This I then hide, when in mobile, and vica versa.

Is this a bad practice?

```
var parentElement = document.getElementById("cssmenu");
var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("ul");
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
lis[i].setAttribute("style","background-color: black");
```

I have now learned, that I can easily use javascript, to hide and show menu, this is a better solution, since most people do have javascript enabled nowadays, right?
But then I come to mobile, and not everyone here have js, is this correctly assumed, or is js implemented in their systems?
I am thinking, I can alter the above code, to hide and show my 'ul', but naturally not hide the first ul, the menu it self.
This way, I want to keep my hover function in my desktop, but have an onclick in my mobile, seems much better to only hide that onclick button in the desktop version...

Now, it seems that any hover action I set in my desktop stylesheet, also effects my mobile-stylesheet.. I understand this is because it render's it all into one stylesheet, and naturally, it finds hover, and uses this in my android as well..
Is there any good way to solve this problem, I have naturally considered removing the hover effect, and have a clickable menu all around, seems mobile's make the hover in css kinda old-time, and I have also looked at :focus, and :active, but not considered active as much..
Is active the way to go here, and in that case, would I have to implement this in my menu-items somewhere?

```
var parentElement = document.getElementById("cssmenu");
var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("ul");
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
lis[i].setAttribute("style","display: inline");
```

something like this is probably what I am looking for, I will experiment a little with it and see how it goes, but some pointers to what is the best practice, also for future, would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I've noticed that you have posted "answers" to most of your own questions. This is not very typical, but the bigger issue is that most of your answers are more like follow-up responses to other people's questions. It's great that you are being thorough, but I think you should take care not to view stackoverflow as a discussion forum. These kinds of answers do not fit SO's Q+A format.